Macro to update shape color on click in PowerPoint
I am trying to create a macro that will toggle a shape's color upon clicking. I've assigned the macro below to a shape, and it should execute with a click. However, when I click, nothing happens. Do I need to name the shape something specific? or is there something wrong in the VB language?
Sub ChangeShapeColour(ByRef oShp As Shape)
    Dim oSh As Shape
    ' IF the shape's .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = red color:
        If oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(199, 70, 52) Then
    ' Change it to green:
        oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(117, 156, 108)

        End If
        
    ' IF the shape's .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = green color:
        If oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(117, 156, 108) Then
    ' Change it to red:
        oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(199, 70, 52)
        
        End If


End Sub


You've got several excellent answers here regarding your code. But also, understand that   macros assigned to shapes will ONLY trigger in slide show view, not in any other view.

Toggle Shape Color

For those new to PowerPoint, in the Insert tab under the Illustration group, there are Action Buttons at the bottom of the Shapes menu that can utilize (call) the following codes as they are.

The Issue

In the sub's signature, shp As Shape already means Dim shp As Shape so you mustn't do it again inside the sub.
It makes no difference whether you add ByVal or ByRef since an object is always passed ByRef in VBA.
By introducing two variables and a With statement, you can make your code more readable:

Sub ToggleShapeColorYourCode(shp As Shape)
    
    Dim Red As Long: Red = RGB(199, 70, 52) ' some red color
    Dim Green As Long: Green = RGB(117, 156, 108) ' some green color
    
    With shp.Fill.ForeColor
        
        If .RGB = Red Then .RGB = Green
        If .RGB = Green Then .RGB = Red
        
        ' With the previous two 'If' statements you are implying the following:
        
        If .RGB <> Red And .RGB <> Green Then ' it's neither
            ' do nothing!?
        End If
    
    End With

End Sub


The logic of your code yields the following: If the shape is green, make it red.
How?

If the shape is green, the 1st statement will ignore it while the 2nd statement will make it red.
If the shape is red, the 1st statement will make it green, while the 2nd statement will make it red again i.e. it will remain red forever at the cost of the resources needed to make the two conversions happen.


There is a third implicit (hidden) condition (case) that you may have forgotten about i.e. when the color is neither red nor green. In this case, nothing will happen i.e. the current shape's color will remain forever.
You have to decide what should happen in this case. In the continuation, I have opted for Red.

The Fix

You must introduce an ElseIf and/or an Else clause into the If statement. Alternatively, you can use the IIF function or the Select Case statement.

1.) If Long
Sub ToggleShapeColorIFLong(shp As Shape)
    
    Dim Red As Long: Red = RGB(199, 70, 52) ' some red color
    Dim Green As Long: Green = RGB(117, 156, 108) ' some green color
    
    With shp.Fill.ForeColor
        If .RGB = Red Then
            .RGB = Green
        ElseIf .RGB = Green Then
            .RGB = Red
        Else ' it is neither
            .RGB = Red ' or Green, your choice
        End If
    End With

End Sub

2.) If Short
Sub ToggleShapeColorIfShort(shp As Shape)
    
    Dim Red As Long: Red = RGB(199, 70, 52) ' some red color
    Dim Green As Long: Green = RGB(117, 156, 108) ' some green color
    
    With shp.Fill.ForeColor
        If .RGB = Red Then
            .RGB = Green
        Else ' it is not red
            .RGB = Red
        End If
    End With

End Sub

3.) IF Shorter
Sub ToggleShapeColorIfShort(shp As Shape)
    
    Dim Red As Long: Red = RGB(199, 70, 52) ' some red color
    Dim Green As Long: Green = RGB(117, 156, 108) ' some green color
    
    With shp.Fill.ForeColor
        If .RGB = Red Then .RGB = Green Else .RGB = Red
    End With

End Sub

4.) IIF
Sub ChangeShapeColorIIf(ByVal shp As Shape)
    
    Dim Red As Long: Red = RGB(199, 70, 52)
    Dim Green As Long: Green = RGB(117, 156, 108)
    
    With shp.Fill.ForeColor
        .RGB = IIf(.RGB = Red, Green, Red)
    End With

End Sub

5.) Select Long
Sub ToggleShapeColorCaseElse(shp As Shape)
    
    Dim Red As Long: Red = RGB(199, 70, 52) ' some red color
    Dim Green As Long: Green = RGB(117, 156, 108) ' some green color
    
    With shp.Fill.ForeColor
        Select Case .RGB
            Case Red: .RGB = Green
            Case Green: .RGB = Red
            Case Else: .RGB = Red ' or Green, your choice
        End Select
    End With

End Sub

6.) Select Short
Sub ToggleShapeColorCase(shp As Shape)
    
    Dim Red As Long: Red = RGB(199, 70, 52) ' some red color
    Dim Green As Long: Green = RGB(117, 156, 108) ' some green color
    
    With shp.Fill.ForeColor
        Select Case .RGB
            Case Red: .RGB = Green
            Case Else: .RGB = Red
        End Select
    End With

End Sub


VBA PowerPoint works in mysterious ways, but this should work:
Sub ChangeShapeColour(oShp As Shape)
With oShp.Fill
    If .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(199, 70, 52) Then
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(117, 156, 108)
    Else
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(199, 70, 52)
    End If
End With
End Sub

